# React state stays the same in callback functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code, I have a provider component. In this component, I have state objects and some functions that change state. The problem is I want to change state depending on state value but in my functions, state stays the same as it was initialized.

Part of my code:

```
const AppContextProvider = () => {
  const [historyState, setHistoryState] = useState({
    historyLength: 0,
    currHistoryIdx: 0,
  });

  const historyAdd = () => {
    if (historyState.currHistoryIdx < historyState.historyLength)
      setHistoryState((state) => ({
        historyLength: state.currHistoryIdx + 1,
        currHistoryIdx: state.currHistoryIdx + 1,
      }));
    else
      setHistoryState((state) => ({
        historyLength: state.historyLength + 1,
        currHistoryIdx: state.historyLength + 1,
      }));
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{ state, centerState, rpState, historyState, functions }}
    >
      <App />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I need to check the state to make a decision on how to change it, but in this function, the state always stays the same as it was initialized and because of this, my condition doesn't work properly.

I can get actual state only inside the `setHistoryState` function using the `state` parameter, but this solution doesn't suit me because I have more complex functions. Also if you use `useEffect` to check if the state changed, it will show the actual state in console.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know if this is can solve your problem because I have never set state on a Context component, but try to do this: setHistoryState({historyLength: historyState.historyLength + 1, currHistoryIdx: historyState.currHistoryIdx + 1}). As I said, I don't know if this can help you to fix the problem, if not just let me know and I will try coding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The state updater function can be used as such, a function, with any additional side-effect-free logic.

Move the condition inside the `setHistoryState` updater function:

```
const historyAdd = () => {
  setHistoryState((state) => {
    // here, state will always be up-to-date.
    if (state.currHistoryIdx < state.historyLength) {
      return {
        historyLength: state.currHistoryIdx + 1,
        currHistoryIdx: state.currHistoryIdx + 1,
      };
    }
    return {
      historyLength: state.historyLength + 1,
      currHistoryIdx: state.historyLength + 1,
    };
  });
};
```

> I can get actual state only inside `setHistoryState` functions using state parameter, but this solution doesn't suit to me because I have more complex functions.

No matter the use-case or the complexity, using the latest state inside the updater function is likely the solution to this problem.

It can also be used in conjunction with `useEffect` to trigger changes, etc.

As an example, [here's a more complex situation which is solved with the same solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63572421/1218980)