# Should Promises be avoided in React components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I've recently came across this error in React:

> warning.js:36 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or
>   mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the
>   BillingDetails component.

After digging I found out that this is caused because I do `setState` in unmounted component like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchBillings(this.props.userType);
}

componentWillReceiveProps({ userType }) {
    if (this.props.userType !== userType) {
        this.fetchBillings(userType);
    }
}

fetchBillings = userType => {
    switch (userType) {
        case USER_TYPE.BRAND:
            this.props.fetchBrandBillings()
                .then(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false }));
            return;
        default:
    }
};
```

`fetchBillings` is a [redux-axios action creator](https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware) which returns a promise

```
export const fetchBrandBillings = () => ({
    type: FETCH_BRAND_BILLINGS,
    payload: {
        request: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: Endpoints.FETCH_BRAND_BILLINGS,
        },
    },
});
```

The problem is that when user moves fast on site, component can be unmounted at the time promise resolves.

I found out lot of places around the project where I do something like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const { router, getOrder, params } = this.props;
    getOrder(params.orderId).then(action => {
        if (action.type.endsWith('FAILURE')) {
            router.push(`/dashboard/campaign/${params.campaignId}`);
        }
    })
}
```

and now I begin to think that using Promises in components could be anti-pattern as component can be unmounted at any time...

Comment: I think it's much more idiomatic `redux` to use the promise to mutate the state and then use `react-redux`'s `connect` to hook up the component with the state. Then  the library takes care of ensuring that you don't inappropriately mutate the component.

Comment: No problem with promises, but you have to do it in componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps, not before or during rendering

Comment: @Nevosis that wouldn't solve to the problem because the promise can still resolve after the component unmounts. @Tomasz You need to either cancel the promise when the component unmount, but that can be tricky and painfull, or move  `isLoading` to your `redux`'s store.

Comment: @AnisSmail having `isLoading` flag in component seems to be good place especcialy if you need to render few of the same components and each of them has to do api request. Anyway `isLoading` is just one of the case, sometimes you want to do route change for example.

Comment: ok I get it. maybe look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37771337/4099279 , I don't know if there is a cleaner way to "stop" axios request

Comment: @Tomasz I'm not saying it isn't. Conceptually it is, in practice I find it cumbersome.

Comment: @Tomasz, look at this : https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#cancellation It is possible to cancell an ongoing axios request. I don't know how redux-axios handle it thow

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that when user moves fast on site, component can be unmounted at the time promise resolves.

Since native promises are not interruptible, this is completely natural and should be expected at all times. You can overcome this in various ways, but you will ultimately need to track whether the component is still mounted, one way or another, and just don't do anything when the promise resolves/rejects if it's not.

Also, from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) regarding componentWillMount:

> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

Considering this, I'd suggest using `componentDidMount` for initiating your fetch instead. Overall:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.fetchBillings(this.props.userType);
}

componentWillReceiveProps({ userType }) {
    if (this.props.userType !== userType) {
        this.fetchBillings(userType);
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
}

fetchBillings = userType => {
    switch (userType) {
        case USER_TYPE.BRAND:
            this.props.fetchBrandBillings().then(() => {
                if (this._isMounted) {
                    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
                }
            });
            return;
        default:
    }
};
```

---

*Additionally, although this is not directly related to your question, you will need to consider that you will have multiple parallel fetch calls running in parallel, leading to a data race. That is, the following is just waiting to happen at any time:*

```
start fetch0
start fetch1
finish fetch1 -> update
...
finish fetch0 -> update
```

*To avoid this, you can track your requests with a timestamp.*